# Identical bases conflict in multiple empty member optimization

Tags: c++, templates

I want to use an empty member optimization with a class having two members of user-defined types. As far as I know, the only way to achieve this is two make them my class' parents.

```cpp
template<class Callback1, class Callback2>
struct S: Callback1, Callback2
{
    S(Callback1 c1, Callback2 c2): Callback1(c1), Callback2(c2) {}
    void Method()
    {
        Callback1::operator()();
        Callback2::operator()();
    }
    int field;
};
struct Functor {};
struct Functor2 {};
static_assert(sizeof(S<Functor, Functor2>) == sizeof(int));
```

The problem of this solution is that I cannot instantiate something like `S<Functor, Functor>`. When these two arguments are of the same type, I get a compiler error about two identical parents.
What is the best way to work around this problem?

**Edit:** There must always be two instances of callbacks even if they are of the same type. Any of these callbacks may be empty or not empty (stateful), but the cases when any of them or both are empty should be optimized.

Comment: What's the point of passing the same functor twice? Are you perhaps looking for a way to make it work with a single functor?

Comment: @devoin Do you want to inherit twice or do you want to remove duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of involving multiple inheritance from the same base would go something like;

```
template <class Callback> struct FirstBase : Callback {};
template <class Callback> struct SecondBase : Callback {};

struct Functor1 {};
struct Functor2 {};

template<class Callback1, class Callback2> struct S: FirstBase<Callback1>, SecondBase<Callback2> {int field;};
```

Answer (score 1):

The straight forward solution for getting around the problem is to specialize.

```
template<class Functor>
struct S<Functor, Functor> : Functor {
  int field;
};
```

If that causes too much repetition, you can reuse the code for the two functor version by introducing a special "null functor".

```
struct NullFunctor { /* Whatever implementation makes sense in your domain */ };

template<class Functor>
struct S<Functor, Functor> : S<Functor, NullFunctor> {};
```

Alternatively, if your goal is to allow client code to use `S` with either a single functor or two different ones, you can specialize on a template parameter pack.

```
template<class ...Functors>
struct S;

template<class Functor>
struct S<Functor> : Functor {
};

template<class Functor1, class Functor2>
struct S<Functor1, Functor2> : Functor1, Functor2 {
};

template<class Functor> 
struct S<Functor, Functor>; // Same functor used twice.
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, however it is not my use case. There must always be two separate functors. Updated my question to better reflect my use case.

Answer (score 0):

This was surprisingly hard. The following code allows inheriting from an arbitrary list of types and each type of the list will be used exactly once as base:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct is_among;

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct is_among<T, T, Ts...> : std::true_type {
    using value_t = T;
};

template<class T, class U, class... Ts>
struct is_among<T, U, Ts...> : is_among<T, Ts...> {};

template<class T>
struct is_among<T> : std::false_type{};

template<class SFINAE, class... Ts>
struct inherit_once;

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct inherit_once<std::enable_if_t<!is_among<T, Ts...>::value>,T, Ts...> : inherit_once<void, Ts...>, T {};

template<class T, class... Ts>
struct inherit_once< std::enable_if_t<is_among<T, Ts...>::value>, T, Ts...> : inherit_once<void, Ts...> {};

template<>
struct inherit_once<void>{};

struct A{
    void operator()(int){}
    };

struct B : inherit_once<void, A, A> {
    int i;
};
int main(){
    static_assert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(B));
    B b;
    b(1);
}
```

Edit: Having multiple instances:

```
#include <utility>

template<class F, size_t id>
struct id_wrap: F {};

template<class id_seq, class... Funcs>
struct OptHelper;

template<class... Funcs, size_t... ids>
struct OptHelper<std::index_sequence<ids...>, Funcs...> : id_wrap<Funcs, ids>... {};

template<class... Funcs>
struct Opt: OptHelper<std::index_sequence_for<Funcs...>, Funcs...> {int i;};

struct Functor {
    void operator()(int) {}
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    static_assert(sizeof(Opt<Functor,Functor>) == sizeof(int));
    Opt<Functor> f{};
    f(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, however it is not my use case. There must always be two separate functors. Updated my question to better reflect my use case.